# No se pueden ejecutar scripts desde Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, jenkins

lo hemos intentado por todos los medios, pero no somos capaces de ejecutar scripts de Selenium Webdriver desde el Jenkins, nuestra intención es ejecutar los scripts en un orden aunque de momento estamos probando a ver si se ejecuta uno al menos con los siguientes comandos:

```
javac EnviarPruebaDeIngles.java
java EnviarPruebaDeIngles
```

Lo curioso es que la Build la realiza satisfactoriamente, ya que reconoce el workspace y el pom.xml, o eso creemos. Lo cierto es que hemos seguido infinidad de tutoriales y en ninguno somos capaces de reproducir ninguna ejecución.

**El error en consola dice que no encuentra la clase EnviarPruebaDeIngles.java**

Os dejamos por aquí la configuración de Jenkins:

[image: Log de consola]

```
Started by user admin

Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo Parsing POMs Established TCP socket on 57342 [JenkinsDemo] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.13.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\apache-maven-3.8.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\apache-maven-3.8.1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main C:\Users\xxxxxxx\apache-maven-3.8.1 C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-4.12.jar C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar 57342 <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\pom.xml install [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO]
----------------------< JenkinsDemo:JenkinsDemo >----------------------- [INFO] Building JenkinsDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ JenkinsDemo
--- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\src\main\resources [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ JenkinsDemo --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\src\test\resources [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] No sources to compile [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] No tests to run. [JENKINS] Guardando informes de test [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ JenkinsDemo --- [INFO] Installing C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\target\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.m2\repository\JenkinsDemo\JenkinsDemo\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar [INFO] Installing C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\pom.xml to C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.m2\repository\JenkinsDemo\JenkinsDemo\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  3.337 s [INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-09T12:20:50+02:00 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ Esperando a que Jenkins finalice de recopilar datos [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\pom.xml to JenkinsDemo/JenkinsDemo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo\target\JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to JenkinsDemo/JenkinsDemo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar channel stopped [JenkinsDemo] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins13221465416928573076.bat

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo>javac EnviarPruebaDeIngles.java  error: file not found: EnviarPruebaDeIngles.java Usage: javac <options> <source files> use
--help for a list of possible options

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo>java EnviarPruebaDeIngles  Error: Could not find or load main class EnviarPruebaDeIngles Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EnviarPruebaDeIngles

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsDemo>exit 1  Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
```

[image: La configuración del job]

[image: La configuración del job 2]

[image: Conf job 3]

[image: Árbol Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias cosas mal:

- Si estás compilando con Maven, no tiene sentido tratar de hacerlo posteriormente "de modo manual"
- La clase que quieres compilar está dentro de `JenkinsDemo/src/com/jenkins/demo`, no en la raíz del proyecto.
- Realmente deberías asegurarte de que se crea el fichero jar (maven dice que te lo ha creado en el log) dentro de la carpeta `JenkinsDemo/target` y ejecutar ese jar directamente con `java -jar target/JenkinsDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` o algo similar, dependiendo de los parámetro u opciones que necesitas